# Which SVN clients support locks with expiration date?

Tags: svn, locking

The API documenation of pysvn, and the output of the `svnadmin lslocks` command seems to indicate that locks in svn can have an expiry date after which they, when accessed again, are removed from the server.

However, the svn handbook doesn't explain anything about expiry dates although `Expires:` does shows up in the handbook's demonstration of the command line output of `svnadmin lslocks`.

Neither svn.exe nor TortoiseSVN seem to make accessible this feature. Is it really implemented in the svn library and just a matter of the client making use of it, or has it just been stubbed for future releases of subversion?

Comment: It is implemented, however there may be issues with svn.1.8+apache servers, gonna be fixed in the upcoming svn release. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201403.mbox/%3CCAJrmsKZm81vS73kr2Z1jV3MmtTXqSSWWzgJ58vsBvE5i3jOgmw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

libsvn-based clients (command-line `svn` client, TortoiseSVN etc) do not support *setting* lock expiration, afaik.

However, Subversion supports lock expiration because some [generic webdav clients such as MS Office and OpenOffice applications](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.webdav.clients.html#svn.webdav.clients) always set lock expiration when accessing a versioned document in Subversion repository.